# Javascript: Create an element and then set an img src using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/info?ip=76.171.110.176&port=25565', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('lastUpdate').textContent = "Last Update: " + data.last_update + "(GMT-6)";
    document.getElementById('version').textContent = "Minecraft Version: MC Release V" + data.version;
    document.getElementById('serverVersion').textContent = "Server Version: Last Update " + data.motd;
    if (data.status == "success") {
        document.getElementById('online').textContent = "Server is online!";
        if (data.players === 0) {
            document.getElementById('playerListHTML').textContent = "No players are currently online.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.playerList.length; i++) {
                printList.push(data.playerList[i] + ".png");
                var img = document.createElement("img" + [i]);
                img.setAttribute("id", "image" + [i]);
                document.getElementById("image" + [i]).src = "http://signaturecraft.us/avatars/5/face/" + data.playerList[i] + ".png";
            }
            //document.getElementById('playerListHTML').textContent = printList;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('online').textContent = "Server is not online... try again later.";
        document.getElementById('playersListHTML').textContent = "Server is not online... try again later.";
    }
});
```

Basically, I want to get a JSON from a website's API that gets the list of players online as an array, create an element for each player online, then set the src (image source) to the player's face.
Here is an example of the src URL that I want when I am online: http://signaturecraft.us/avatars/5/face/BtheDestroyer.png

If anyone could figure out how to get this stupid thing working, I would REALLY appreciate the help!

Comment: What's not working?  What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: the url doesn't return status=='success' for me but maybe its an auth thing. you also may find it easier to use jQuery for updating the ui.

Comment: +1 I don't understand why you are using jQuery to get the content, then ignoring it for the rest of it.

Comment: the created image element is not appended to the dom tree

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery convert all the constructs to use jQuery syntax.

One problem I could see is the created image elements are not added to the dom structure so try

```
$.getJSON('https://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/info?ip=76.171.110.176&port=25565', function (data) {
    $('#lastUpdate').html("Last Update: " + data.last_update + "(GMT-6)")
    $('#version').html("Minecraft Version: MC Release V" + data.version)
    $('#serverVersion').html("Server Version: Last Update " + data.motd)
    if (data.status == "success") {
        $('#lastUpdate').html()
        if (data.players === 0) {
            $('#playerListHTML').html("No players are currently online.")
        } else {
            $('#playerListHTML').empty()
            $.each(data.playerList, function (idx, player) {
                $('<img/>', {
                    id: 'image[' + idx + ']',
                    src: "http://signaturecraft.us/avatars/5/face/" + player + ".png"
                }).appendTo('#playerListHTML')
            })
        }
    } else {
        $('#online').html("Server is not online... try again later.")
        $('#playersListHTML').html("Server is not online... try again later.")
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p987f/)